# bad output(monocolor) with Java Advanced Imaging api

Tags: java, java-2d, imaging, jai

I m having a sample image(sorry for the type of image) which i m feeding into JAI code to get a compressed image.

Now the output image i m getting is in mono-color. I don't know why is the output is abnormal but other images are getting processed just fine.

The sample original and processed images are -

Original Image -

[image: sample image]

Processed Image -

[image: Processed Image]

The JAI code to process the image -

```
private static final String JAI_STREAM_ACTION = "stream";

private static final String JAI_SUBSAMPLE_AVERAGE_ACTION = "SubsampleAverage";

private static final String JAI_ENCODE_FORMAT_JPEG = "JPEG";

private static final String JAI_ENCODE_ACTION = "encode";


private static final String JPEG_CONTENT_TYPE = "image/jpeg";
private int mMaxWidth = 800;

//private int mMaxWidthThumbnail = 150;

private byte[] resizeImageAsJPG(byte[] pImageData, int pMaxWidth) throws IOException {

    InputStream imageInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pImageData);

    SeekableStream seekableImageStream = SeekableStream.wrapInputStream(imageInputStream, true);
    RenderedOp originalImage = JAI.create(JAI_STREAM_ACTION, seekableImageStream);
    ((OpImage) originalImage.getRendering()).setTileCache(null);
    int origImageWidth = originalImage.getWidth();

    double scale = 1.0;
    /*
    if (pMaxWidth > 0 && origImageWidth > pMaxWidth) {
        scale = (double) pMaxWidth / originalImage.getWidth();
    } */
    ParameterBlock paramBlock = new ParameterBlock();
    paramBlock.addSource(originalImage); // The source image
    paramBlock.add(scale); // The xScale
    paramBlock.add(scale); // The yScale
    paramBlock.add(0.0); // The x translation
    paramBlock.add(0.0); // The y translation

    RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    RenderedOp resizedImage = JAI.create(JAI_SUBSAMPLE_AVERAGE_ACTION, paramBlock, qualityHints);
    BufferedImage scaledImage = null ;

    ByteArrayOutputStream encoderOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JAI.create(JAI_ENCODE_ACTION, resizedImage, encoderOutputStream, JAI_ENCODE_FORMAT_JPEG, null);    
    //byte[] resizedImageByteArray = encoderOutputStream.toByteArray(); 
    System.out.println("This is from exiting JAI");
    return encoderOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

With imgScalr I m also getting the same output.

In openJDK with JAI I get the error -

```
javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "encode"
```

With imgScalr in openJDK-

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid argument to native writeImage
```

Any other library i can use in java to get the desired result.

Regards

Comment: I see you reference the open jdk. Do you get similar results using oracle's jre?

Comment: No there are no outputs with openJDK, only the exceptions. With Oracle's JDK i get the outputs.

Comment: What is the JAI class you reference actually doing?

Comment: the code with the quality hints is compressing the image but with good quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to convert the image to 3Byte_BGR -

```
private synchronized BufferedImage getScaledImage1(BufferedImage imageBytes)
{
    BufferedImage scaledImage = null;
    int type = 0;
    try
    {
        type = imageBytes.getType();
        if(type == 0 || type ==6) {
            int w = imageBytes.getWidth();
            int h = imageBytes.getHeight();
            BufferedImage newImage = 
            new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(imageBytes, 0, 0, null);
            g.dispose();
            imageBytes = newImage;
        }
        scaledImage = Scalr.resize(imageBytes, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY,2000,
        Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
    } catch(Exception e) {        
    }        
    return scaledImage;
}
```